# Why this function is discontinuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be $-2/x*\cos(1/(x^2)) + 2*x*\sin(1/(x^2))$ for $0 < x \le 1$ and $f(0) =0$. I compute the limit of $f(x)$ for $x \to 0$ and is not defined. It is not clear to me why limit is undefined implies $f$ is discontinuous? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $f$ is continuous at $0$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exists and is equal to $f(0)$.